# Difference between two PHP variable definitions

Tags: php

I have two variable definitions, and I am trying to understand the difference between the two so I can merge them into one.

**PHP Definition 1:**

```
$page = $_GET['page'];
```

**PHP Definition 2:**

```
$page = 0;
 if(isset($_GET['page'])){
    $page = (int) $_GET['page'];
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second definition will suppress any error encountered when `$_GET['page']` isn't set by not trying to assign it to anything.

The `(int)` part in the second definition will cast `$_GET['page']` to an integer value. This will inhibit any attacks you might get, although you should still be careful.

Finally, `$page = 0` simply sets a default value for `$page`. If there is no value in `$_GET`, `$page` will remain with a value of `0`. This also ensures that `$page` is always set, if you're using it in code below your snippet.

I don't know what you mean by `merge them into one`; the second snippet is an extension (and improvement) of the first.

Comment: So I should just be able to use the second one in place of the first, and it should work fine?

Comment: That is correct, providing the second piece of code gives you the functionality you want (only taking integers from `$_GET['page']`).

Comment: A shorter version can also include `$page = (isset($_GET['page']) ? (int)$_GET['page] : 0);`

Comment: Nice one @Brad, although ternary expressions can be confusing to some :-)

Comment: @Brad Christie yes, I get the idea of that expression, but I think for now I'm going to stick with the other notation... still learning here.

Answer (score 1):

The first code block assigns to `$page` whatever value is in `$_GET['page']`.

The second one assigns a default value of `0` to `$page`. And the `if` statement will check first to see if `$_GET['page']` is set (to avoid warnings). If it is set indeed, it will cast the value of `$_GET['page']` to an integer and assigns it to `$page`.

Comment: so if the first one isn't defined as an integer, what is it defined as?

Comment: @stefmikhail: PHP isn't strongly typed, so (assuming a whole number is passed in) it will still be seen as an integer within php. The cast is "sanitizing" the input from the user, given it's in a URL (GET) variable and can be manipulated easily.

Comment: @stefmikhail: It will be whatever value `$_GET['page']` contains. If it contains `123abc`, that's what will be assigned to it. However, the second one will assign `123` to it. Read [string conversion to numbers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) for full details.

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally use:

```
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? (int) $_GET['page'] : 0;
```

Or array_key_exists.

Comment: If OP doesn't understand the two code snippets in the question, how do you expect OP to understand your answer without an explanation?